# Cannot execute javascript code from loaded page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I created a page that show a gallery of images (**imagenes.html**):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/zepto.min.js"></script>  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/slider.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="gallery"></div>
    <div id="image"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

And the javascript code is (**slider.js**):

```
$(function() {

function loadSliderImage() {    
    var i, f, n;

    for (i = 1; i < 49; ++i) {
        n = ((i < 10) ? "0" : "") + i
        f = n + "-120.JPG";
        $("#gallery").append("<img src='images/cocinas/thumbs/" + f + "' rel=" + n + "></img>");
    }
}

$("#gallery").on('click', 'img', function() {
    $("#image").html("<img src='images/cocinas/small/" + $(this).attr("rel") + "-600.JPG' rel=" + $(this).attr("rel") + "></img>");
});

$("#image").on('click', 'img', function(e) {
    var url = "images/cocinas/large/" + $(this).attr("rel") + "-980.JPG";
    window.open(url, 'KitchenMaster', "width = 980, height = 670, scrollbars = no");
    e.preventDefault();
});

loadSliderImage();

});
```

If I execute the **imagenes.html**, works fine but if I execute the page **index.html** that load the **imagenes.html**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/zepto.min.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/km.js"></script>
<title>Gallery</title>      
</head>
<body>
<div id="content"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

with the javascript code (**km.js**):

```
$(function() {

$("#content").load("imagenes.html");

});
```

the page **imagenes.html** not works fine (the javascript code **slider.js** does not run)

Can you help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding HTML inside HTML, it wont work, you can't have two head and body section in same HTML. instead in **imagenes.html** keep only those two divs '**gallery**', '**image**' and javascript stuff then load it in **index.html**